# Acer E5-573G Touchpad

Tags: acer

Sorry for my english, I'm italian. I have a problem with Linux on my laptop: the touchpad doesn't work.
This is the "xinput" output:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ Logitech  USB WheelMouse                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

"SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN" is the touchpad, and this is the output of "xinput -list --long 12":

```
SYN1B81:01 06CB:2970 UNKNOWN                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
This device is disabled
Reporting 8 classes:
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIButtonClass
    Buttons supported: 12
    Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
    Button state:
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 0:
      Label: Rel X
      Range: 0.000000 - 1236.000000
      Resolution: 12000 units/m
      Mode: relative
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 1:
      Label: Rel Y
      Range: 0.000000 - 898.000000
      Resolution: 12000 units/m
      Mode: relative
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 2:
      Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
      Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
      Resolution: 0 units/m
      Mode: relative
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
    Detail for Valuator 3:
      Label: Rel Vert Scroll
      Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
      Resolution: 0 units/m
      Mode: relative
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
    Scroll info for Valuator 2
      type: 2 (horizontal)
      increment: 30.000000
      flags: 0x0
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
    Scroll info for Valuator 3
      type: 1 (vertical)
      increment: 30.000000
      flags: 0x0
    Class originated from: 12. Type: XITouchClass
    Touch mode: dependent
    Max number of touches: 3
```

Then I tried "xinput enable 12", but it didn't work.
The touchpad works without problems when I boot from the Windows 10 install disk.

Thanks in advance and sorry, again, for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Go to bios settings by pressing F2 before booting. Then go to main tab and find touchpad. Change it from advanced to basic. Save and exit by pressing F10 .